# diff in different periods and variable

Tags: python, dictionary, feature-engineering

I would like to create a function to transform some specific features in a `df` with the `pandas` method `.diff` in the different indicated periods.

I got it in a two step mode, but I am sure this can be one liner, iow, it can be simpler.

Given the following `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Category":["A"]*10+["B"]*50+["C"]*15+["D"]*100,
             "foo":[np.random.random_sample() for i in range(175)],
             "bar":[np.random.random_sample() for i in range(175)]})
```

So by using a `dict` I can set the colnames and define the `diff` level I want to perform:

```
dict_diff={"foo":[1,2],"bar":[3,4]}
```

In order to set the names and transform at same time, the code I developed is:

```
pd.concat(map(lambda dict_items: df[dict_items[0]].diff(periods=dict_items[1]).rename(f"{dict_items[0]}_diff{dict_items[1]}"), dict_diff.items()),axis=1)
```

Whats missing/wrong?

I can not iterate over the value list. As `dict_items[1]` is a list, there is something I need to do.

As a result:

I would get a `df` with the new additional columns `foo_diff1`,..., as indicated in the dict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need list comprehesion and some reduce function in a manner that you can concat with pandas:

```
import functools
import operator
 
def functools_reduce(a):
    return functools.reduce(operator.concat, a)

pd.concat(functools_reduce(map(lambda dict_items: [df[dict_items[0]].diff(periods=diff_value).rename(f"{dict_items[0]}_diff{diff_value}") for diff_value in dict_items[1]], {"foo":[1,2],"bar":[3,4]}.items())),axis=1)
```